# Django: Site-Wide URL Prefix

Tags: django, django-urls

I've built a Django site that will live at the root when it's live. Right now it's functioning perfectly at the IP address. For testing purposes, the client has pointed a proxy url at it, but the url has /folder/path in it, so none of the URL patterns match. I put (/folder/path)? into all the url patterns so they now respond, but all of the links are broken because I'm using the {% url %} tag and while the url patterns will match the optional path, they don't include it in that tag.

Clearly I can just hard-code /folder/path into all of my urls (well, into all of the url includes) until testing is complete, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You manage this when you deploy your application, by correctly setting the `WSGIScriptAlias` in your Apache configuration (assuming you're using mod_wsgi, which you should be doing). This is passed on to Django, which then automatically prefixes all URL reverse lookups with the correct value. You shouldn't need to do any manual mucking about with prefixes.

Comment: To clarify, in other words, ensure the URL mount point used with WSGIScriptAlias in the back end matches the URL that it is mounted at with any front end proxy. As long as they are the same then should all work fine with respect to prefixes.

Comment: @Daniel what about nginx + uwsgi deployment?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I am deploying my django app in apache locally on xampp and I have this `WSGIScriptAlias /dj/ "c:/xampp/htdocs/commons/mod.wsgi"` but what you are it seems I have to prefix the urls in my already developed app with /dj/. If I understand you correctly dj whould be prefixed automaitcally but that not the case. What am i getting wrong

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I'm also have problems with this approach. Some people get the right URLs (with the prefix) and others without it. Any ideas of why this could be happenning?

Comment: To be clear, this post is dated. You should be using Gunicorn to deploy your projects.

Comment: @student-ksu that's a very strange comment. gunicorn is indeed a fine way to deploy your app, but so is uwsgi, and so is mod_wsgi which continues to be supported and developed.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpouse I use URL_PREFIX in settings.py and add it in each include in urls.py. I also add it at the beginning of MEDIA_URL, for all images/css/js links to work. But I would also like to hear about some more tricky solution?

Answer (score 0):

if WSGIScriptAlias doesn't work or you can't set it up for some reason, remember that the include() function in a urlconf adds the prefix to all URLs. you can create an urlconf which includes your current root urlconf and mount it at the prefix, and then point your settings.py file to that urlconf.

Disclaimer: haven't tried this myself, but it should work.